# Integration test for kubernetes deployment with helm on openshift

Tags: kubernetes, testing, ansible, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to use ansible or helm test to test all resources are up and running after the deployment of  ansible automation platform (automation controller, private-automation-hub) on openshift.

Currently, I am using ansible assertion to check the deployments but seems like I can use --atomic with helm commands and check the all resources are up after the helm deployment.

Can you help me with ansible to check all the resources (not only deployments but all resources I deployed with helm chart)? maybe example code or also if possible with helm test some examples?

Thank you.

```
- name: Test deployment
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
#  vars:
#    deployment_name: "pah-api"
  tasks:
  - name: gather all deployments
    shell: oc get deployment -o template --template '{{"{{"}}range.items{{"}}"}}{{"{{"}}.metadata.name{{"}}"}}{{"{{"}}"\n"{{"}}"}}{{"{{"}}end{{"}}"}}'
    register: deployed_resources
#  - name: print the output of deployments
#    debug:
#      var: deployed_resources.stdout_lines
  - name: Get deployment status
    shell: oc get deployment {{ item }} -o=jsonpath='{.status.readyReplicas}'
    with_items: "{{ deployed_resources.stdout_lines }}"
    register: deployment_status
    failed_when: deployment_status.rc != 0

  - name: Verify deployment is running
    assert:
      that:
        - deployment_status.stdout != 'null'
        - deployment_status.stdout != '0'
      fail_msg: 'Deployment {{ deployed_resources }} is not running.'
```

Currently I only check for deployments but it would be nice to check all resources (I deployed with helm chart) with ansible or via helm test?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Ansible Helm module. The `atomic` parameter is available out of the box: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/helm_module.html